JDBC SOURCE connector adding extra " and \s to json columns
I am using kafka JDBC Source connector to fetch the JSON data from table (using a complex SQL query that generates the JSON data using JSON functions of Postgres DB) and using the JsonConverter to publish to kafka topic.
Since the result would have nested JSON, the data when published to kafka topic is having extra " and \ added by converter. Basically the JSON field is treated as String when converted into JSON.
Is there any support to handle nested JSON in connector?
Below is the connector properties:
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
Below is the connector properties:
    "name" : "source-connector",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "topic.prefix" : "<Name>",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<DbName>",
    "connection.user" : "<User>",
    "connection.password": "<PW>",
    "poll.interval.ms" : 3600000,
    "query": "<Custom Query having json datatype result>",
    "mode": "bulk",
    "transforms":"createKey, RenameField",
    "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.createKey.fields":"tpnb",
    "transforms.RenameField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
    "transforms.RenameField.renames":"<Few renames>",
    "db.timezone": "UTC",
    "batch.max.rows": "1000",
    "tasks.max" : "1"

Expected output:
{"key1":"value1",
"NestedKey": [{"nKey1":"nValue1"},{"nKey2":"nValue2"}]
}

Output produced by connector:
"NestedKey": "[{\"nKey1\":\"nValue1\"},{\"nKey2\":\"nValue2\"}]"
}


I don't think Confluent jdbc source connector supports this https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/overview.html#json-and-jsonb-for-postgresql. Maybe Debezium does, but you can't specify a query with it
